# Capture text in a line and replace text on the next line with it, using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to generate a .po file out of an existing one, needing the basic `en_US` resource file.

It contains sequences of this kind:

```
# DE language source file.
#
"Project-Id-Version: ID-VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: <somebody@some.org>\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-01-01 00:01+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2023-01-02 00:02+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: somebody\n"
"Language-Team: somebody\n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

msgid "(none)"
msgstr "(keiner)"

msgid "Unknown error"
msgstr "Unbekannter Fehler"

msgid "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
msgstr "Der faule Fuchs springt über braunen Hund"
```

that I try to get like:

```
# DE language source file.
#
"Project-Id-Version: ID-VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: <somebody@some.org>\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-01-01 00:01+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2023-01-02 00:02+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: somebody\n"
"Language-Team: somebody\n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

msgid "(none)"
msgstr "(none)"

msgid "Unknown error"
msgstr "Unknown error"

msgid "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
msgstr "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
```

I'd prefer `sed` or `awk` to do the job, but I am not aware how to capture the `(none)` part and copy it to the next line instead of `(keiner)`.

I think of a replacement, but also capture to add directly a split line with `\n` to generate a second line (for `msgstr`), and delete the pair line (the one with `msgstr`).

How could this be achieved with `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Just added one more sample, enough to generalize.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: @markp-fuso, tis is not a bug report. I simply couldn't do it. Why should I list here my failed attempts? Wouldn't that be spam? Now I learn the below code, from both answers, and here is a true flaw that  Ican't mark both as answers.

Comment: Paolo's answer was neater and more accurate, and he had answered earlier than me. Since I saw that dear @Paolo had answered you using awk, I wanted to also provide an answer using sed. So please choose his answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I am still testing and finding more cases. Having a comment at the beginning of the file shows that Paolo's answer is truly correct because this keeps those comments. I admit, I would like a sed solution, but it seems difficult to achieve.

Comment: In my experience, trying to find solutions, has lead me to many answers, but search engines seem to take also the wrong answers into account, so no, I won't pollute the internet with that even some would decrease the question. I am sure somebody would find this useful, thanks to the nice people that answered it.

Comment: Regarding "Why should I list here my failed attempts? Wouldn't that be spam?" The site exists to help people with their code, not to provide free code, so you should list your failed attempts so we can help you and no, it wouldn't be spam it'd be standard procedure. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```bash
$ awk '$1 == "msgid" {t=$1; $1=""; v=$0; $1=t} $1 == "msgstr" {$0=$1 v}; 1' file
msgid "(none)"
msgstr "(none)"

msgid "Unknown error"
msgstr "Unknown error"

msgid "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
msgstr "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
```

whenever msgid is found, store all but the first column in a variable and then whenever msgstr is found, replace all but the first column with the variable.

Comment: This works fine for `awk`. I guess `sed` is more delicate.

Answer (score 2):

With special thanks to dear @EdMorton, here is the solution to this question using sed.

```
sed '/^msgstr /d; s/^msgid \(.*\)/&\nmsgstr \1/' input.po
```

Output

```
# DE language source file.
#
"Project-Id-Version: ID-VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: <somebody@some.org>\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-01-01 00:01+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2023-01-02 00:02+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: somebody\n"
"Language-Team: somebody\n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

msgid "(none)"
msgstr "(none)"

msgid "Unknown error"
msgstr "Unknown error"

msgid "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
msgstr "The lazy fox jumps over brown dog"
```

- `'/^msgstr /d` - This part is used to delete any lines that begin with the string `msgstr`
- `s/^msgid \(.*\)/&\nmsgstr \1/` - This part searches for lines that start with `msgid`  and captures the rest of the line using the `\(.*\)` pattern and the captured text is then referenced using `\1` and also the `&` symbol represents the entire matched line and the substitution replaces the matched line with itself (`&`) followed by a newline (`\n`), the string `msgstr` , and the captured text from the original line!

Comment: This almost works! It wipes any other content there, besides changing the `msgid/msgstr` pairs.

Comment: It should keep other lines too.

Comment: @mike Since you started your question until now, you have made several revisions to your wording. In the future, I kindly request that you take some time to fully gather your thoughts before writing your question here. This will help ensure clarity and accuracy.

Comment: Yes, sure, but it's unexpected to me to have a `sed` solution that would affect other lines than targeted. The presumption is the mother of failure.

Comment: The first one works fine. The second one compacts the file by removing the empty line. First one is enough.

Comment: To keep the comments, I wrote this: `$ sed -n '/^msgid/s/msgid "\(.*\)"/\nmsgid "\1"\nmsgstr "\1"/p;/^["#]/p' input.po`

Comment: this is the final file, just that my file has more `msgid/msgstr` sequences, but hat is not really relevant. The current solution works, although I can't imagine a generic solution to the `^["#]`, but this is it for the files I have. I have not the liberty to publish concrete strings.

Comment: Indeed, `^\(\#\|"\)` does the same as `^["#]`, but when I say I would prefer a more generic solution, it means to leave everything else as it is in the file but the pairs `msgid/msgstr` pairs. To me, beyond the particular .po files I have, specifying the exact list of chars needs to be extended for any new case. This was my point of failure.